# Twitter bootstrap fluid layout designing trouble

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a fluid layout with twitter bootstrap but unfortunately there is some mistake in how i am approaching it.

Please advise where am i doing wrong. I have created a navbar div which contains navbar-inner and within that i have container. Within a container a row.

In a row i have 3 elements the project-name , the navigation bar and the login section.

On shrinking the page the project name stays in correct position, the navbar is hidden to show up only on click and the third the login section gets dislocated.
I can't  understand why it is getting dis located.

I have uploaded the code on ---> http://jsfiddle.net/GgzgB/2/
but due to missing images the background is not shown.
PS: this is my first css attempt

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id='cssmenu' class="navbar-inner">
    <!--<div class="navbar-custom">-->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <!--<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>-->
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div><!--end of first col -span2-->
                <div class="span7">
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end of nav-collapse collapse-->
                </div><!--end of second col - span5-->
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="login">
                        <form class="form-signin">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span1"> 
                                    <div class="row">    
                                        <input type="text" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Username">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <input type="password" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span1">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-medium pull-right">Sign in</button></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--end of inner 1st row-->
                            </form>
                        </div><!--end of login-->
                    </div><!-- end of span3--> 
                </div><!-- end of row -->
            </div><!-- end of container -->
        </div><!-- end of inner -->
    </div><!-- end of navbar navbar-fixed-top -->
</body>
```

Comment: Please copy your code to jsfiddle.net so we can take a look at what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are trying to create a fluid layout, you'd use row-fluid as opposed to just row.

Additionally, you're putting the login form in the same row as the project-name and navbar.

I'm not going to perfect this for you, but this gets you much closer by using row-fluid, and creating a new row after the navigation:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id='cssmenu' class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span2">
                        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span7">
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--end of nav-collapse collapse-->
                    </div><!--end of second col - span5-->

                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="login">
                            <form class="form-signin">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span12"> 
                                        <div class="row-fluid">    
                                            <input type="text" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Username">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <input type="password" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span12">
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-medium pull-right">Sign in</button></div>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div><!--end of login-->
                    </div><!-- end of span3--> 

                </div><!-- end of row -->
            </div><!-- end of container -->
        </div><!-- end of inner --> 
    </div><!-- end of navbar navbar-fixed-top -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Often with CSS less is more, so I think you could start off with simplifying your code a bit by removing all the row/span definitions in the navbar, they aren't really necessary. Next, the [Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) is quite good, so its always worth looking through them in detail to see if what you want has already been defined there.

From the documentation: "Align nav links, search form, or text, use the .pull-left or .pull-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in the specified direction." Also, we can use the "navbar-form" class to layout the login form, rather than the grid classes. So lets pare the code down a bit, and then you can perhaps get closer to what you are after.

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id='cssmenu' class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class='active '><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end of nav-collapse collapse-->
                <div class="login pull-right">
                    <form class="form-signin navbar-form">
                        <input type="text" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Username">
                        <input type="password" class="input-header-small pull-left" placeholder="Password">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-medium pull-right">Sign in</button></div>
                    </form>
                </div><!--end of login-->
            </div><!-- end of container -->
        </div><!-- end of inner -->
    </div><!-- end of navbar navbar-fixed-top -->
</body>
```

This may not be your final solution, but I think it would be a good starting point.